# Не могу подключить файл стилей

Tags: php

Есть небольшой проект на slim framework. В корне сайта лежит папка public с index.php
Шаблоны лежат в корне в папке templates. Там же лежит папка assets в которой лежат стили.

Использую шаблонизатор twig. Для загрузки использую функцию get_uri().

В мастер-шаблоне выглядит примерно так

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ get_uri() }}templates/assets/css/style.css">
```

Но проблема в том что файл не подключается и я не могу понять где ошибка.

Comment: А в коде страницы создаваемый элемент как отображается? Он вообще там появляется? Откройте страницу браузером и в инструментах разработчика посмотрите, что там появилось.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался